# zinsco breaker box in garage

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair, circuit-breaker, fire

Just got this place. This panel is in the garage. It is connected to the house main on a 50amp breaker. the panel in garage has 8 circuits going out to 20 outlets and one light fixture on ceiling. I know Zinsco is bad fire hazard and want to replace. Also curious if I would be able to only use half of the outlets and have a 220 line in garage. Is this possible?
[image]

Comment: Is there any lettering/marking on the cable that carries power into this panel...? It seems far too new to not have a grounding wire in it...

Comment: What a mess! I'm not a pro and I can already see a bunch of violations. It also looks like an old 3-wire feed and you will probably need to add a ground wire to the feed. I'll leave it to the pros to comment further.

Comment: I will take a closer look at the cable and see if any markings and let you know.

Comment: One more question: your main panel is *not* a Zinsco, right?

Comment: no its not. its a square d 200A 24 space thats totally full. lol. this place is 4 bedroom two story house and it literally has 44 outlets in it. the main inside house was zinsco but was changed before I bought it so I assume they had issues with it from the looks of the one in garage.

Comment: Brian, the breakers are hanging on that panel. I would not certify it as safe. Zinsco panels have a problem with arcing to the buss, aluminum buss + loose connections creates arcing, more heat and this is what causes the breakers to fail. With the breakers not being held in horizontally there is a chance for that to happen with the existing 20 amp breakers.  No front cover increases the possibility of damage if the worst was to happen nothing to contain any molten metal.  You haven’t told us the numbers on the feeder to the sub yet. Add ground when upsizing because #10 or 8 is two small now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd suggest selecting a new subpanel with a lot more than 8 spaces.  For expansion room, mainly; if you get busy you can fill it.  (you can run a LOT of stuff on 50A feeder).

You probably weren't imagining a 24-space panel, but the fact is, panel spaces are *laughably cheap*... whereas running out of spaces is a major frustration.  So it really, really is "false economy" to scrimp on the size of the panel.  Buy spaces like you never want to buy them again. Because you don't.

The new panel will be taller and you won't have any trouble getting all the cables fully into the panel and 1/4" past the cable clamp while they are still in the sheath.

A new installation would require a separate neutral and ground.   Also, ground (alone) can be retrofitted.  However, simply replacing the panel to get rid of that Zinsco should not oblige you to upgrade to a grounded feed.  Also, adding individual circuits should not have that effect.

Comment: So if I am able to pull new cable threw to main breaker box inside, will the current 50mp breaker work to run 8 outlets, one ceiling fixture and one 220 outlet work? What size cable and ground would be required for that?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like #10 awg feeding the panel, if so and you leave the existing wire in place you will need to reduce the breaker feeding the wire to 30A. If you replace the cable to 50A capacity of your existing breaker you will you will need (4 conductor) #6 awg copper. It is possible that 4 wire was actually the requirement when the panel was (maybe illegally) installed. The wire must be sized to handle at least the size of breaker feeding the wire.

You can install as many 120 and 240v general purpose convenience receptacles you want, none can individually be fed by breakers greater than the breaker feeding the panel.

If the garage is detached you will need a disconnecting means for the new panel. A two-pole switch minimum rated for the size of the feed ahead of the panel is all that would be required, but a main breaker is much easier.

The panel has to be rated a minimum of the breaker that feeds it, a larger rated panel is kind of like higher load range tires on a truck. It won't increase your capacity, but not prohibited, and less likely to suffer abuse. (Get at least a 60A rated panel, really even a physically larger 100A will make it easier to make sure the wires can reach breakers and neutral bars.)

The 2020 code requires new or replaced 120v and 240v receptacles in a garage to have GFCI protection. 240v receptacles will require 2 full size breaker spaces, full size breakers quickly turn 6 space 12 circuit panel into a 6 circuit panel.

Also if this is a detached garage some could argue ifs, ands, or buts about if ground rods was or were or if retrofitting panel would require brining grounding up to current code, but no questions asked, ground rods would be the second thing I would do after replacing the feeder breaker with a 30A.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance, it is greatly appreciated. I understand most of that except the feeder breaker with a 30A. Does that mean use a 30A breaker in main box inside house, then the new box in garage i agree, 100A box. I can use the main for shut off then replace my outlets with the gfci outlets and install the 220 line. Would 50A breaker for the 220 line work or something else to meet code? I do want to be up to code or as close as possible so once the box is installed I will definitely try to tackle the ground rod.

Comment: You already have 240v. Both black and red are 120v to ground (neutral). When one leg is +120 the other is -120, and 240v is measured between them. You can't call them +/- because each leg cycles + then - 60 times (hz) a second, when one is positive the other is negative.

Comment: What causes overheating is allowing too much current (amps), kind of like too many lanes of traffic. Voltage is pressure, matter creates resistance. Low resistance allows high flow, pure copper has very low resistance, connecting "short" copper wires directly together or to ground creates very low resistance that allows high current. High resistance creates low flow. Rubber and plastic have very high resistance, so high that almost no current can flow unless very high pressure (voltage) is present.

Comment: Connect too many lanes (amps) of traffic you will get too much flow, the flow will heat the wire and melt the insulation. Your #10 is limited by code to 30A, you need a 30A current breaker in the main panel that supplies the #10 to prevent more than 30A of current from flowing on the #10.

Comment: If you loaded all the breakers in your garage panel 50% you would have 40A on each leg. The wire is only rated for 30A, so if you leave the 50A breaker in your main panel you could overheat the wire.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am going to get supplies and try this out next weekend and I will update my progress with a pic.